# why is \d+ not matching all digits?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
REGEX = /^.+(\d+.+(?=AL|AK|AS|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|DC|FM|FL|GA|GU|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MH|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|MP|OH|OK|OR|PW|PA|PR|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VI|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY)[A-Z]{2}[, ]+\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?).+/
```

I have the following string:

```
str = "fdsfd 8126 E Bowen AVE Bensalem, PA 19020-1642 dfdf"
```

Notice my capturing group begins with one or more digits that match the pattern. Yet this is what I get:

```
str =~ REGEX
$1
 => "6 E Bowen AVE Bensalem, PA 19020-1642"
```

Or

```
match = str.match(REGEX)
match[1]
=> "6 E Bowen AVE Bensalem, PA 19020-1642"
```

Why is it missing the first 3 digits of 812?

Comment: What if the address were `str = "fdsfd 2-8126 E Bowen..."`? Note the end of your regex, `.+/` is the same as `./` (and also the same as `.+$/`). Also, if your regex included just a few state abbreviations (say, 4), that would not change the question and readers would not have to scroll horizontally to read it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The below regex works properly, as you can see at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YWZPKY/1)

```
REGEX = /^.+?(\d+.+(?=AL|AK|AS|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|DC|FM|FL|GA|GU|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MH|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|MP|OH|OK|OR|PW|PA|PR|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VI|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY)[A-Z]{2}[, ]+\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?).+/
```

Note the addition of the question mark near the beginning of the regex

```
/^.+?(\d+...
    ^
```

By default, your first `.+` is being greedy, consuming all digits it can, and still allowing the regex pass. By adding `?` after the plus, you can make it lazy instead of greedy.

An alternative would be to not capture digits, like this:

```
/^[^\d]+(\d+...
```

`[^\d]+` will capture everything except for digits.

Comment: or, use `\D` instead `[^\d]`... similarly, `\S`, `\H`, `\W`, etc see https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes

Comment: If you shorten the regex to use character classes for the second letter of state abbreviations you can greatly reduce the number of steps required to match the string [as seen here](https://regex101.com/r/YWZPKY/2)